# Для чего в RUST нужен знак вопроса?

Tags: rust

```
fn main() {
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn foo() -> std::io::Result<()> {
     let mut file = File::create("foo.txt")?; //здесь
     file.write_all(b"Hello, world!")?; //здесь 
     Ok(())
   }
}
```

Для чего нужен знак вопроса ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`expression?` - это сокращенная запись для `try!(expression)`. [Описание макроса `try!` из руководства по Rust](http://rurust.github.io/rust_book_ru/src/error-handling.html#the-try-macro).

Вкратце. Если `expression` возвращает значение `Err(err)`, то `try!` (или `?`) выполняет немедленный выход из функции: `return Err(err.into())`. Если же значение `expression` - `Ok(v)`, то макрос возвращает `v` и исполнение продолжается.